# Extract included association from ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end
```

Let's say I have 10 articles written by 3 authors.

I have a query a like this:

```
articles = Article.includes(:author).all
```

This will result in 2 queries:

```
Select * from articles limit 10;
Select * from authors where id IN (...)
```

How can I extract the authors from articles in a more elegant way than doing something like:

```
articles.map(&:user).uniq(&:id)
```

The use case would be to display a json with 2 keys, messages and users

```
json.articles(articles, :id, :author_id, :title, :created_at)
json.authors(articles.map(&:author).uniq(&:id), :id, :name)
```

Comment: If you want the authors, why not start there? Get the authors and then the articles for those authors? What's the use case?

Comment: The case was to avoid doing a new query by hand and to use what Rails provides.

Comment: I meant, the business use case? Are you displaying the authors on the side, etc? I only ask, because looping and comparing uniqueness is not effective and it's not common to display related objects (Authors) outside of the context of the original object (Article).

Comment: I updated the answer, I need to display them separated exactly as you think.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `SELECT DISTINCT`, via the ActiveRecord `uniq` method? Note that this differs from the Array `uniq` method that you used, despite having the same name.

```
Author.joins(:articles).group(:id).uniq
```

This generates something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT `authors`.* FROM `authors` INNER JOIN `articles` ON `articles`.`author_id` = `authors`.`id` GROUP BY `authors`.`id`
```

If you need to limit you articles query, you can use `merge`:

```
Author.joins(:articles).merge(Article.where(...)).group(:id).uniq
```